# Android Activity communicating with Tab: Tab is null

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments, android-tabs

For my latest Android application (API level 15) I used the new architecture where each Tab in the GUI is represented by a Fragment class which is registered at a PagerAdapter and Tab events are handled by a TabListener.

However, when I want to send data between two tabs I run into a problem. I used the code samples from [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity) and wrote the following code to send data from a Tab to my Activity:

```
@Override
public void onDataReceived(Map<String, List<Map<Integer, String>>> receivedData) {

    Log.i("CarerActivity:onDataReceived", "Map received by Fragment.");
    Log.i("CarerActivity:onDataReceived", receivedData.toString());
    Log.i("Fragment ID", ""+R.id.configurationfragment);

    TabConfiguration configurationFragment = (TabConfiguration) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.configurationfragment);

    if(configurationFragment != null){
        Log.i("CarerActivity:onDataReceived", "Fragment not null.");
    }else{
        Log.i("CarerActivity:onDataReceived", "Fragment null!");
    }
}
```

The receivedData.toString() is displayed correctly, so the Tab sends its data to the Activity. A Fragment ID is also displayed. After that the output is always "CarerActivity:onDataReceived  Fragment null!" which makes it impossible for me to call any methods of the Fragment (because it is null).

In my R.java the line

```
public static final int configurationfragment=0x7f080001;
```

can be found under

```
    public static final class id{
```

.

Anyone got an idea what I am doing wrong or where to look for the error?

Setup: Samsung Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.0.3, API level 15, Java 1.6, Mac OS 10.8, Eclipse Juno.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an interesting article about [FragmentPagerAdapter](http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html)

> FragmentPagerAdapter will detach each fragment as you swipe through
>   the list, but keep them in memory so they can simply be reattached
>   when the user swipes back. If you have a larger number of Fragments,
>   the FragmentStatePagerAdapter is worth considering as it will remove
>   them, with the downside being they need to be rebuilt as the user
>   swipes back to them. So, if you have fewer, more complex fragments the
>   FragmentPagerAdapter makes sense, but consider
>   FragmentStatePagerAdapter for larger sets.

Basically when you swipe from one fragment to another, the previous fragment is destroyed (= null).

One way to overcome this issue will be to hold the new data in a third party class or in your activity. Then when the fragment is recreated pass it a bundle with the new data.

Here is an exemple :

```
public class PagerUserAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{
    private final static String titles[] = {"Profile", "Badges", "Skills", "Accomplishments"};

    private Bundle args;

    public PagerUserAdapter(FragmentManager fm, CWUser u) 
    {
        super(fm);

        this.args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(Constants.BUNDLE_USER, u);
    }

    public void refresh(CWUser u)
    {
        args.putSerializable(Constants.BUNDLE_USER, u);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
    {
        return titles[position];
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) 
    {
        switch(position)
        {
        case 0:
            return ProfileFragment.newInstance(args);
        case 1:
            return BadgesFragment.newInstance(args);
        case 2:
            return SkillsFragment.newInstance(args);
        case 3:
            return AccomplishmentsFragment.newInstance(args);
        default:
            return ProfileFragment.newInstance(args);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return titles.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) 
    {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class BadgesFragment extends BaseFragment
{    
    public static BadgesFragment newInstance(Bundle args)
    {
        BadgesFragment f = new BadgesFragment();
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        CWUser u = (CWUser) getArguments().get(Constants.BUNDLE_USER);
            //do what you want with your new data   
    }
}
```

In your activity when you get new data, all you have to do is call the refresh method of your adapter with the new data.
This is how I do it, it may have way more elegant solution, I'm open to any suggestion.
The exemple is based on one of my open source app, here is the [project](https://github.com/florianmski/Coderwall-Android) with full code if you want to dig.

Comment: I see... which other approach would you suggest then? I read something about Fragment Transactions. Or is there a better way to do this?